# NZEC Error on HackerEarth

Tags: java

I was trying to solve a challenge on HackerEarth. I tried to submit this code but it shows NZEC run time error on the website. I ran this code on a different PC and it works fine and gives the correct output for all the test cases.

Challenge was to find the **smallest** integer among the given input integers such that when that integer replaces all other integers the sum of all of them should exceed the sum of  input numbers.
The inputs were given in a form of two lines first containing total number of integers and second the integers separated by space.
For eg:
 
INPUT
5
1 2 3 4 5
OUTPUT
4
EXPLANATION
1+2+3+4+5=15
4+4+4+4+4=16
So according to the problem, smallest among these integers is 4. So the code should give the output 4.

I know NZEC is Non Zero Error Code but I want to know  why it is coming in my code and why there is no issue on other Systems.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    class Abc
    {
        public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception
        { 
             Console con = System.console ();

             int n = Integer.parseInt(con.readLine());

             Console conn = System.console ();

             String str = conn.readLine();

             int arr[] = new int [n];

             StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (str);      
             for (int x=0; x<n; x++)
            {

                 int N = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

                 arr[x] = N ;

            }

            int iniSum = 0;
            for (int x=0; x<n; x++)
            {

                 iniSum += arr[x];

            }

            int tempArr [] = new int [n];
            int tempArrPos = 0;
            for (int x=0; x<n; x++)
            {

                 int num = arr [x];
                int checkSum = num*n;
                //System.out.print (checkSum+"\n");
                if (checkSum>iniSum)
                {
                    tempArr [tempArrPos] = num;
                    //System.out.print ("\n\n\t"+tempArr [tempArrPos]);
                    tempArrPos++;
                } 
            }


            //for (int xx = 0; xx < n; xx++)
            //  System.out.print(tempArr[xx]);


            int smallest = 1000000000;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                    if(tempArr[i] < smallest && tempArr[i]>0)
                            smallest = tempArr[i];

            }

            System.out.print(smallest);



        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the error? Any stacktrace?

Comment: also to process an array with the size of `1000000000` will quickly causing OOE?

Comment: To process an array with the size of `1000000000` will quickly causing OOM Exception? You may wan to check and restrict the out-of-bound inputs. e.g. what if the `n` got too big or `n` is -ve.

Comment: Please describe problem statement als0.

Comment: I have updated the problem statement

Comment: I am not processing any array of size 1000000000. This is just an arbitrary number taken for comparision. Also the given inputs integer can't be negative or too big that their sum exceeds the range of int.